# Does references to static properties cause memory leaks

Tags: c#

I have a long-running application that consistently fails due to a memory leak.

I suspect my use of static properties may be the cause. Here's an example of what I have today:

```
public class StaticReferences
{
    public static readonly object Fixed1 = new object();
}

public class ShortLived
{
    public object Object1;
}

public class Doer // This class is instantiated once
{
    public void DoStuff() // This method is called over and over again.
    {
        var shortLived = new ShortLived() 
        {
            Object1 = StaticReferences.Fixed1
        };
    }
}
```

Will an instance of `ShortLived` with its reference to `StaticReferences.Fixed1` (via the `ShortLived.Object1` property) get properly garbage collected once it is out of scope?

Comment: What makes you think there's a memory leak?

Comment: It's a console app that runs a process that takes a couple of hours to complete. It fails with an Out Of Memory exception. I ran it through Jetbrains DotMemory. The unmanaged memory space keeps growing. Managed memorý is stable..

Comment: @JakobGade What does your program do that requires unmanaged memory? Is that part implemented by you or through a 3rd-party component? How is unmanaged memory handled?

Answer (score 4):

No, just referencing global static properties won't create a memory leak. The example you posted is fine. `shortLived` will be cleaned up once its scope is over and the reference to `Fixed1` will get cleaned up when your program exits. Your problem is very likely elsewhere but it's impossible to say from your simple example. Do you have any proof that you're looking at a memory leak?

I suggest you use a memory profiler or get a full memory dump and analyze it (WinDbg is free but there are other, easier to use but pay tools, too). Another tool you can try using is [DebugDiag](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924) from Microsoft (also free) - get a dump and then run it through DebugDiag to get a memory report.

As @EricJ mentioned in his comment, the profiler in Visual Studio 2015 is also a great tool to analyze memory use and it's available in all editions, including the free [Community Edition](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/07/20/performance-and-diagnostic-tools-in-visual-studio-2015/).

Comment: The memory profiler in VS2015 works great, and is available even in the community edition https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/07/20/performance-and-diagnostic-tools-in-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: @EricJ. Thank you, I'll update my answer to include that, too, if you don't mind.

Comment: Sure, it's always a good idea to maintain your answer to be as complete and useful as possible.